# rectangular pulse train in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to implement a rectangular pulse train in python.

I searched scipy and there is no signal that implements.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html

In matlab there is a signal named pulstran:
http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pulstran.html

An example of code in matlab would be like this:

```
T=10; %Period
D=5; %Duration
N=10; %Number of pulses

x=linspace(0,T*N,10000);
d=[0:T:T*N];
y=pulstran(x,d,'rectpuls',D);
plot(x,y);
ylim([-1,2]);
```

[image]
How i could implement this signal in python?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a sample output of the matlab ? There may or may not be a particular inbuilt function but we can surely achieve this behaviour with programming

Comment: Add a link, and we can convert it to an inline picture for you

Comment: thank you, i put the picture

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're looking for just periodic pulse trains, like the example you gave - here's a pulse train that is on for 5 cycles then off for five cycles:

```
N = 100 # sample count
P = 10  # period
D = 5   # width of pulse
sig = np.arange(N) % P < D
```

Giving

```
plot(sig)
```

[image: plot(sig)]

You can replace `np.arange(N)` with your `linspace` here. Note this is not *equivalent* to your code, as the pulses are not centered.

---

And here's a fully configurable pulse train:

```
def rect(T):
    """create a centered rectangular pulse of width $T"""
    return lambda t: (-T/2 <= t) & (t < T/2)

def pulse_train(t, at, shape):
    """create a train of pulses over $t at times $at and shape $shape"""
    return np.sum(shape(t - at[:,np.newaxis]), axis=0)

sig = pulse_train(
    t=np.arange(100),              # time domain
    at=np.array([0, 10, 40, 80]),  # times of pulses
    shape=rect(10)                 # shape of pulse
)
```

Giving:

[image: configurable pulse train]

---

I think this is one of those cases where matlab's `pulsetran` function is more confusing than the one-line implementation of it in python, which is possibly why scipy does not provide it.

Comment: A possible variation specifying active cycle (PWM like) would be: `sig = np.arange(N) % ncycles < ncycles * pwm_ratio`, with `0 < pwm_ratio < 1`.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `square` function from `scipy.signal`:

Verbatim from [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.square.html):

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 500, endpoint=False)
plt.plot(t, signal.square(2 * np.pi * 5 * t))
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
```

[image]

Therefore, for your example, do this:

```
T=10
D=5
N=10
shift = 1/4   # number of cycles to shift (1/4 cycle in your example)
x = np.linspace(0, T*N, 10000, endpoint=False)
y=signal.square(2 * np.pi * (1/T) * x + 2*shift*np.pi)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.xlim(0, T*N)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are nice but I found they are having some problems with `scipy.integrate` so I created 3 types specially keeping in mind `scipy.integrate`:

- Uniform width of pulses and uniform time period (each argument must be a single number).

```html
def uniform_pulse_function(self, t, start, stop, pulsewidth, period, amplitude):
        func = amplitude * np.where((t > start and t < stop and (t % period <(pulsewidth))),
                                    1, 0)
```

- Uniform Pulsewidth but different amplitudes (each argument must be a single number except amplitude which should be a tuple of same length as the number of pulses that can be accommodated within start and stop):

```html
func = (amplitude[int(t//period)])*np.where((t>start and t<stop and (t%period<(pulsewidth))), 1, 0)
        return func
```

- Non-uniform Pulsewidth and non uniform amplitude but period should remain constant (Amplitude and Pulsewidth  should be a tuple of same length as the number of pulses that can be accommodated within start and stop while period should be a single number):

```html
def custom_pulse_function(self, t, start, stop, pulsewidth, period, amplitude):
        func = (amplitude[int(t//period)]) * np.where((t > start and t < stop and (t % period < (pulsewidth[int(t//period)]))), 1, 0)
        return func
```