# Is there a way of doing a rectangular shape function positive values?

Tags: python, function, numpy

I am trying to do a rectangular shape function for a signal with ten seconds with values for 1 between 1 and for 4 seconds a 0 for the rest, I looked other problems but they only seemed to cover for repeating pulses while I just want this single pulse. I already tried the code below, but since I am very new to programming I can not seem to get it to work. I also saw this question but since it only gives the absolute values it does not work for me [rectangular pulse train in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698213/rectangular-pulse-train-in-python)

```
y=np.zeros(10)
def rect(x):
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    if 1<=x<=4:
        y=1
    else:
        y=0
    return rect(x)
f1=rect(y)
plt.plot(y,f1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do: Long way using your functional approach and a short vectorized way. I present both:

**Longway**: Call the function within a for loop and append the values of y to a list.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

def rect(i):
    if 1<=i<=4:
        y=1
    else:
        y=0
    return y

f1 = []
for i in x:
    f1.append(rect(i))

plt.plot(x,f1)
plt.show()
```

**Short way**: Create a conditional mask and apply it to your y-array to fill it with 0 and 1 depending on the condition.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
mask = (x>=1) & (x <=4)

y = np.where(mask, 1, 0)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll have to look into this mask since I don't know much about it but from the long one I understood it.

Comment: I tried to vote on it but I do not seem to have the reputation to do so

Comment: @MiroFelicianoDringdosSanto: No issues. You need a minimum reputation of 16 I think to vote.