# ON/OFF keying plots with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698213/rectangular-pulse-train-in-python) addresses how to generate rectangular pulses at regular intervals. [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29698584/5919064) points to a fully configurable pulse train.

Now, suppose I want to plot an ON/OFF keying pattern, where my pulses have a fixed repetition rate `rrt` and duty cycle `t`.
If I start from an array of 0/1, I could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
L = 30       # Number of pulses
rrt = 1      # Repetition rate
t = 0.3      # Duty cycle

ookInput = np.random.randint(2, size=L)
x = np.arange(0, L*rrt-0.01, 0.01)
y = [ookInput[int(i/rrt)] if (i%rrt)<t else 0 for i in x]
```

But maybe there is a simpler way to do that.

Is this generalisable to bell-shaped signals instead of rectangular ones?

Comment: Executing your code results in an error:
IndexError: index 30 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 30

Comment: @dobkind Corrected, thanks for spotting that!