# Rectangular Pulse Train - input period and pulse_width as array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, lambda, scipy

I have been trying for hours now to use this : [rect pulse train](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698213/rectangular-pulse-train-in-python) for my usecase, but I wasn't able to manage that. The rest of this code is working well!

I have a array with the pulse_width for each individual pulse. I do not know how to change this code to make it work. At the Moment the pulse train is generated with a fixed pulsewidth `rect(0.004)`.

```
def rect(T):
    """create a centered rectangular pulse of width $T"""
    return lambda t: (-T/2 <= t) & (t < T/2)

def pulse_train(t, at, shape):
    """create a train of pulses over $t at times $at and shape $shape"""
    return np.sum(shape(t - at[:,np.newaxis]), axis=0)
```

In the `pulse_train()` function you have to call `rect()` to put the pulsewidth, how can I use an array of values instead of one fixed value?

```
sig = pulse_train(
    t=np.arange(0,509,0.005),     # time domain
     at=np.array([0, 10, 40, 80]),# times of pulses array of times where to input rect
#    shape=rect(0.004))           # shape of pulse length    
     shape=rect(inputlength))
```

I hope someone can and is willing to help me! Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following table:

| FIRST NAME | ROLE | PHONE NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | Landlord | 303-817-1021 |
| Bob | Boss | 720-171-2341 |
| Jill | Sister | 303-871-1234 |
| Jane | Mother | 303-791-1271 |
| Joe | my lawyer | 303-191-9912 |

Note that the phone number `303-817-1021` is in the same row as `Sarah` because that phone number ***belongs to*** Sarah.

Python's panda's library is designed so that for every row, `R` of a table, there exists an object `X` such that all of the information in row `R` belongs to object `X`.

For example, you might have a table containing data on houses for sale:

| ADDRESS | BEDROOM COUNT | BATH COUNT | PRICE | SQUARE FOOTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 906 S Norfolk St, Aurora, CO 80017 | 3 | 2 | $410,0004 | 106.342 |

I see what you are doing.
You want a table having multiple columns.
The fact that `X` is in the same row as `Y` is pure-coincidence.
`X` and `Y` are not attributes of the same object just because they are in the same row.

The `pandas` library is not really designed for that.
It is a bit like you are using a wrench instead of a screw-driver.
`pandas` is probably the wrong tool for the job.

However, you can make it work.

My recommendation is that you simply have only one row in the table (two rows if you include the column headers)

You can install the `tabulate` library by using pip.
Type the following command on the command-line:

```
python -m pip install tabulate
```

Here is some python code for you:

```python
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

veggies = [
    "carrot",
    "broccoli",
    "asparagus",
    "cauliflower",
    "corn",
    "cucumber",
    "eggplant",
    "bell",
    "pepper"
]

sweets = [
    "cookies",
    "donut",
    "cake",
    "lolipop",
    "ice-cream",
    "banana-split",
    "Sundae",
    "muffin",
    "jelly",
    "beans",
    "pie",
]


data = [{
    'VEGTABLES':"\n".join(veggies),
    'SWEETS': "\n".join(sweets)
}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

The output looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
|    | SWEETS    | VEGTABLES   |
|----+-----------+-------------|
|  0 | cookies   | carrot      |
|    | donut     | broccoli    |
|    | cake      | asparagus   |
|    | lolipop   | cauliflower |
|    | ice-cream | corn        |
|    | banana    | cucumber    |
|    | split     | eggplant    |
|    | sundae    | bell        |
|    | muffin    | pepper      |
|    | jelly     |             |
|    | beans     |             |
|    | pie       |             |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```