# How to transform a np.array into a function?

Tags: python, function, numpy, interpolation, transformation

I have the following `np.array` which describes a rectangular wave. I would like to transform it **into a callable function** with a continuous argument. The `np.array` is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import rand


def piecewise_control( off_times,amp_inj, period_inj ):

   def select(T):
       
       return lambda t: (-T/2 <= t) & (t < T/2)

   def pulse_train(t, at, shape):
       
       return np.sum(shape(t - at[:,np.newaxis]), axis=0)



   for i in range(1,len(off_times)):

     off_times[i] += off_times[i-1]  + period_inj

 
  
   return  amp_inj*pulse_train(t,off_times,shape=select(period_inj))               


t=np.linspace(0,100,10000)
off_times = 10*rand(10)
period_inj = 1
amp_inj = 1 

control = piecewise_control(  off_times,amp_inj, period_inj )

plt.plot(t,control)
plt.show()
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698213/rectangular-pulse-train-in-python) inspired me.

The plot is the following:

[image]

The question is: can we **transform** the array `control` into a function with a continuous argument?

Of course if we did:

```
def ccontrol(t, control):
      return control[t]
```

unfortunately we would get a function which only depends on **integers**.

Comment: Which floating variable do you mean?

Comment: @Tarik sorry I removed that word because it was misleading. I want something callable just as a function like `sint(t)`.

Comment: Which array do you want to transform into a function? Can you provide the function signature (arguments) and the expected return?

Comment: @Tarik the array is `control` which is defined via the function `piecewise_control`. I would like to have this array just as a callable function defined for each argument. I thought that an interpolation technique or a dense output would have been a key point.

Answer (score 3):

You can [subclass `numpy.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html) and implement the `__call__` method:

```
import numpy as np

class MyArray(np.ndarray):
    def __call__(self, idx):
        return self[idx]

control = np.random.rand(100)
control_view = control.view(MyArray)

print(control_view(5), control[5])
```

For interpolation you can use [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html). In fact, interpolation routines [can return functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) that you can call with any input, not necessarily integers.

Comment: Your solution gives the same output of  my `ccontrol` function.

Comment: @Siderius, right, but it's a callable array, as opposed to a separate function. Now that you edited the question saying you need to call this function with floating-point numbers, `scipy.interpolate` does exactly that.

Comment: wrapping the index with **int()**:
`return self[int(idx)]`
would do the trick here. 
(zero-order interpolation)